# Store SQL query message/Print Statement in file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to store SQL Query Message into the File.

For Example: This is my query

```
Select Getdate()
```

The Result is:

```
2016-07-15 18:12:24.007
```

and the message is:

> (1 row(s) affected)

I Want to store the message into file with `extension.log`

OR

How can I store `Print` Statement result in file. This will be helpful

Can anyone help me out this.

Comment: This has the solution you're looking for: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic914307-391-1.aspx

Comment: ...why do you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Is there a specific table/column/statement you're interested in?  Why not just [log from the database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/logging-queries-and-other-t-sql)?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Enterprise Manager, right click the T-SQL query window, select Results To then click Results to File.

Comment: Yes, but this is to store query result not message. I want to store only message.